# Python Dataframe: Randomly delete rows with initial condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 Col1 Col2 
  a1   1
  a2   1
  b1   2
  b2   2
  b3   2
  b4   2
```

I want to randomly delete 2 of the rows if Col2 = 2. Example output:

```
 Col1 Col2 
  a1   1
  a2   1
  b1   2
  b4   2
```

What is the best way to do this? Thank you:)

Comment: Is the dataframe exactly this size? What if there are 30 rows with 2 in Col2? Do you want to delete 50% of these rows or exactly 2 of them?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution but it works

First get index with respect to condition `Col2 == 2`

```
index = df.index[df.Col2 == 2].tolist()
```

then "randomly" choose two rows to remove

```
import random
idx = random.sample(index, 2)
df.drop(index=idx)
```

Comment: the random.sample works like: index= pre-defined where only the columns are indexed, where you have it to 2, and 2= number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

The one line solution could be:

`df.drop(df.query('Col2 == 2').sample(frac=.5).index, replace=True)`

where frace denotes the percentage of your delete amount in this case half of it, and replace means you overwrite the orginal dataframe)